# Strange behaviors of arrays holding buffered image data in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends Canvas implements Runnable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 160;
  public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
  public static final int SCALE = 3;
  public static final String NAME = "Game";

  private JFrame frame;

  public boolean running = false;

  private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,
                  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

  private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                  .getData();


  public Test() {
          setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
          setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

          frame = new JFrame(NAME);

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          frame.pack();

          frame.setResizable(false);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
  }



  public synchronized void start() {
          running = true;
          new Thread(this).start();
  }

  public synchronized void stop() {
          running = false;
  }

  public void run() {

          while (running) {
                 render();
          }
  }

  public void render() {
      for(int i = 0; i< pixels.length ;i++){

              pixels[i]=0xff00ff;

      }
          BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
          if (bs == null) {
                  createBufferStrategy(3);
                  return;
          } 

          Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
          g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
          g.dispose();
          bs.show();

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
          new Test().start();
  }

}
```

This is some code that I have written which displays a screen filled in with pink and also isolates the area which is troubling me. I've been watching a few java game tutorials recently and one thing they all have in common is they use this:

```
 private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

This code absolutely boggles my mind because, as shown in the Test class, once the pixels array is edited, the edited information is not sent back to the buffered image. It looks as if the array holds a link to the information in the buffered image rather than extracted information. I would appreciate  some confirmation or any additional information regarding this line of code.

Just for clarification, I did lookup this question and found several answers on stack exchange but the answers don't explain the code but rather suggest other ways of accomplishing a similar goal. Like I said before, I come across this code a lot and it would be in my best interest to understand it. From what I have seen, this code appears to have gotten popular after notch used it in his game called minicraft which he created during ludum dare.

Comment: So, you say that if we modify the pixels array, the image gets modified too?

Comment: yes the for loop right under the render method is setting all the pixels in the image to pink.

Comment: I'm not sure what the boggling is all about. It returns a reference to the array that underlies the image. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I suppose in this context it is hard to understand my confusion but originally there were several classes which passed this array through several methods. I was confused because I have never used code that references information in this way. Since you seem to understand this concept better than I do, If I showed you that line of code without any explanation, would you know the array is just referencing the data from the buffered image rather than an extraction of it? If so, what part of it would give it away?